# How to FIX Error -> NetworkingError: read ECONNRESET and Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: express, amazon-s3, file-upload, multer

I have tried to upload large size file to aws s3 location storage using multer package. I mentioned my code. upto 5 kb files have been uploaded successfully. But large file is not uploading.
Please any one suggest me...

This is my route file

```
module.exports = app => {
  const s3 = require("../controllers/s3.controller.js");
  const multer = require('multer');
  const crypto = require("crypto");
  var storage = multer.memoryStorage();
  var upload = multer({storage: storage});  
  var router = require("express").Router();
  router.post('/upload', upload.single("file"), s3.doUpload);
};
```

s3.controller.js

```
const s3 = require('../config/s3.config');
const s3BucketName = process.env.BUCKET;

exports.doUpload =  (req, res) => {
    let bucketName = s3BucketName;
    bucketName = bucketName + "/testingCourse";
    const params = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: req.file.originalname, 
        Body: req.file.buffer
    }
    s3.upload(params, (err, data) => { 
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send("Error -> " + err);
        }
        res.send({
          status:200,
          message:"OK",
          data:req.file.originalname 
        });
    });
}
```

File is not uploading, I got the response,

```
F:\newapi\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:31
            throw err;
            ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:526:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (F:\newapi\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (F:\newapi\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (F:\newapi\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at ServerResponse.send (F:\newapi\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:158:21)
    at ManagedUpload.callback (F:\newapi\app\controllers\s3.controller.js:21:7)
    at ManagedUpload.cleanup (F:\newapi\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\s3\managed_upload.js:629:10)
    at Response.<anonymous> (F:\newapi\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\s3\managed_upload.js:566:28)
    at Request.<anonymous> (F:\newapi\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:369:18)
    at Request.callListeners (F:\newapi\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (F:\newapi\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (F:\newapi\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:688:14)
    at Request.transition (F:\newapi\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (F:\newapi\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:14:12)
    at F:\newapi\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (F:\newapi\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (F:\newapi\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:690:12)
    at Request.callListeners (F:\newapi\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:116:18)
    at Request.emit (F:\newapi\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (F:\newapi\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:688:14)
    at Request.transition (F:\newapi\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (F:\newapi\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:14:12) {
  message: 'Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client',
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT',
  time: 2020-09-15T10:50:27.365Z
}
```

Any one please suggest me!...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This error you are having because when you are getting an error you are sending a response after that you are also sending a response with status 200

so, just return that response when you get any error

```
if (err) {
          return res.status(500).send("Error -> " + err);
        }
```